# Is there a way to play sounds from an Arduino without using a sound shield?

Tags: analogwrite, digital, sound, digital-analog-conversion

I would like to play a wav file (spoken words) from my Arduino.  I do not want to add a sound shield.  Is there a way to play a sound through an output pin?  The quality does not have to be great.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it without an sd card? I really need to know for a school project that we have to finish in like 2 days. help?

Answer (score 8):

I helped someone with a similar question. The results are in my github repo at https://github.com/linhartr22/count. This example uses the PWM library and includes a reference to the article I used to learn how to convert audio files to MP3 with proper settings for the PWM libary. It plays audio through an 8 ohm speaker or a piezo buzzer connected directly to the Arduino.

Answer (score 4):

The [PCMAudio](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PCMAudio) example shows how to play audio data via PWM. Note that you will need to access the MCU at a low level in order to do this; the Arduino libraries don't provide enough control over the hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can - see http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Wav-Player-Using-Arduino/

Space is quite limited, unless you use an SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did a project yesterday to play recorded voice.
You don't need a speaker module.

Just connect the speaker via a resistor to one of Arduino PWM output. Then Connect a micro-sd card module. Format your micro-sd card with FAT32 Option.

Use Sample wave converter to convert your sound files and select the options as 16,000Hz Mono 8Bit. You are all done. Use [tmrpcm](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki) library. It's all easy.

Answer (score 0):

old post but still a good question...

Here is a tutorial for playing 8 bit 33khz audio using the Adafruit M0 Express. You can play ~60 seconds of audio from the 2MB onboard flash through the 10bit Analog out pin.
https://github.com/hydronics2/SamdAudio

two other audio board solutions that offer near 16bit quality...

- Adafruit's circuit python boards [itsbyitsyM0](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3727), [M4](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3800), feather M0. Same as above but using the circuit python interface instead of Arduino.
- [teensy3.2](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2756), teensy3.5, teensy3.6 (you can play out using the Analog pin without the audio shield but the audio shield has a nice 1/8" jack

[Teensy Tutorial](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Audio.html)

[Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-audio-out)

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange! I am a bit puzzled by your answer because it is **specifically** about not using external hardware like a shield, but "to play a sound through an output pin". Thus your answer does not address the question at all.

Comment: @NickGammon The boards suggested are not shields or add-on boards but instead alternative Arduino (like) hardware. I agree it is 100% to the question but it is still a worthy answer for those visiting this question.

Comment: @NickGammon hey Nick! I love your work.. I use your tutorials all the time. Yeah I guess I forgot to say that you can play 20-60 seconds of audio from onboard flash. The Adafruit M0 has 2MB of onboard external SPI flash.

Answer (score 0):

@Hoytman i think this arduino library can help you a lot https://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/